# Как проверить соединение с базой данных MS SQL на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, администрирование

Необходимо проверить соединение с базой данных MS SQL на удаленной Ubuntu-машине (Ubuntu 18.04). Как я понимаю, мне нужен MS SQL-клиент, которому можно отдать `ConnectionString`, после чего он скажет, смог ли подключиться либо нет. Есть ли такой клиент на Ubuntu?

Пока так и не смог в интернете найти его. Находил такой [клиент для mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html), но не знаю, будет ли он работать для соединения с MS SQL (полагаю, что нет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для `SQL Server` существует `sqlcmd` его можно поставить и на Ubuntu (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu).

Подключиться можно с помощью команды: `sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P <your_password>`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Успел еще найти `mssql-cli`. Вроде как `mssql-cli` появился позже